# Suddenly can't send E-Mails with Apple Mail to Gmail SMTP

Tags: email, gmail, apple-mail, smtp

I have a weird problem that started just today. I am using Apple Mail on a Leopard machine, connecting to Gmail. Fetching e-mail works just fine. My SMTP settings are also correct. Still, I can't send mail, it will display a pop up saying that "transferring the content to the mail server" failed (translation from German, could be different in English OS X versions).

I have verified the following:

- My SMTP settings are definitely correct. I have not changed them and the issue appeared today.
- Also, I went through the Apple online configuration for Gmail accounts and did not have to adjust any setting.
- I can run network diagnosis and it will connect to both POP and SMTP servers without a problem (all green lights)
- The Telnet details will show me the HELO message from the Gmail servers, so there's no authentication failure.
- Console.app will not show any messages related to "mail" when I try to send the mail, so there's no specific error message
- The mail I'm trying to send does not have an attachment, it is plaintext only
- I can login to gmail.com and send mails without a problem
- The recipient address exists and contains no syntax errors
- I can also not send mails to myself
- When using another IP and ISP (through VPN), it still doesn't work

As for my settings: I connect to `smtp.gmail.com` and for advanced settings I choose password-based authentication with user: `firstname.lastname@gmail.com` and my password. I let Apple Mail try the default ports (for SSL and TLS, respectively).

Again: I have not changed a thing between yesterday and today.
What is causing that strange behavior? Any help would be much appreciated.

**If you have the same issue, please don't answer below. If you have no real answer to the problem, make it a comment on the original question**.

Comment: It seems like Google is having some problems today. I can't even log into my Google account without 502: Server Errors. This may be the cause.

Comment: Hm that's strange but it could be possible. It surprises me though that I can connect by `telnet`.

Comment: Thanks for the amendment, I will put this into the question, too, if you don't mind. Or maybe let it be migrated to webapps..

Comment: Never mind, at least I am confident this issue will resolve itself. Initially I thought maybe the problem was something different.

Comment: +1 for **If you have the same issue, please don't answer below.**

Answer (score 1):

From time to time I get errors when sending mail through Gmail's SMTP server. It always solves itself without my intervention. I just need to wait a few minutes/hours.

I would abandon Google's SMTP server were it not for keeping a history of my received/sent mail on Gmail.